# strdup with stringstreams causes valgrind errors

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have the following problem: I am writing a C++ program that has to wrap around a C library, so when I interact with the library I always have to use `char*` instead of `std::string` for all operations. In order to avoid working with `char*` as much as possible, I do the formatting with stringstreams, for example like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ostringstream str;

  str << argv[0] << "+" << "hello";

  const char *s = str.str().c_str();

  char *y = strdup(s);

  // this I would give to a library function

  cout << y << endl;

  free(y);

  return 0;
}
```

As far as the output goes, the program correctly outputs "./test+hello". However, valgrind gives me a lot of errors of the type

```
==30350== Invalid read of size 1
==30350==    at 0x402B858: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30350==    by 0x4213475: strdup (in /usr/lib/libc-2.16.so)
==30350==    by 0x41B2604: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.16.so)
==30350==  Address 0x4341274 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 25 free'd
==30350==    at 0x4029F8C: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30350==    by 0x410387A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==30350==    by 0x41B2604: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.16.so)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 const char *s = str.str().c_str();
```

The str() returns a string object. You get a pointer to some internal data of it using c_str, then at the end of the line the string object is deleted. But you still have a pointer to the deleted internal string.

You need to do it like this -

```
std::string s = str.str();
const char* s = s.c_str()
```

to ensure that the string isn't deleted.

Comment: Would it work in all cases if you would write `char *y = strdup(str.str().c_str());`?

Comment: Yes that would work too - as you copy the string before its memory is deleted and don't keep a copy of the pointer afterwards.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yes.  The lifetime of the temporary is until the end of the full expression.  (I'd actually prefer something succinct like this, but opinions vary.  You don't want to introduce a lot of unnecessary intermediate variables, but you don't want expressions to be too complicated either.  Where the cut off point is situated depends on who you ask.)

Comment: @James Kanze "The lifetime of the temporary is until the end of the full expression." That was the wording I was looking for in my original answer but my mind was blank about the right phrase.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for the clarification. Maybe the OP could want to just keep the `std::string` instance and pass the `.c_str()` result to any library function which is happy with a `const char*` instead of `char*` too. That saves an allocation and a copy :).

Comment: @JonasWielicki That would, of course, be the usual approach.  For that matter, _if_ the called function needed a writable `char*`, I'd use `std::string tmp = str.str();` and pass `&tmp[0]`.  About the only time I might use `strdup()` is if _I_ were providing a C interface, and needed to return a dynamically allocated string (documented as such).